# a point in full shift space that has a dense full orbit and a nowhere dense forward orbit

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

Let $(\sum_2, \sigma)$ be full shift space, where $\sum_2 = \{(...\,x_{-2}\,x_{-1}\,x_0\,x_1\,x_2\,...)| x_i = 0,1\}$ and  $\sigma(...\,x_{-2}\,x_{-1}\,x_0.\,x_1\,x_2\,x_3...) = (...\,x_{-2}\,x_{-1}\,x_0\,x_1\,.x_2\,x_3...)$.

I need to prove that there is a point in full shift space whose full orbit is dense but the forward orbit is nowhere dense.

Note that the full orbit of a point $x$ is defined by $O_\sigma (x) = \{\sigma^n(x) | n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and the forward orbit is $(O_\sigma)^{+} (x) = \{\sigma^n(x) | n=0,1,2,...\}$

What I know is that if a dynamical system is transitive, then by definition it has a full orbit that is dense. Also, if $f : X \to X$ is a homeomorphism of a compact metric space and $f$ has a dense full orbit,  then it has a **dense forward orbit**, given $X$ has **no isolated points.**

So, what does an isolated point in $\sum_2 $ look like?

Comment: What is the topology on $\Sigma_2$?

Comment: its the product topology.

Comment: How does that work for density, are not then all points isolated? We are speaking of the product topology on $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb Z}$?

Comment: In fact, periodic points are dense.

Comment: It is a trivial exercise to show that there are no isolated points. But what does it have to do with the title of the question?

Comment: @JohnB I see, because we can always find $y$ such that $x$ and $y$ agree on the first $n+1$ number of terms so the result follows from the proximity theorem. 

I was just thinking of the theorem I've stated at the end and thought that would help me figure out this problem

Comment: Almost like that, you need to do it on both sides at the same time, since it is two-sided. For the example, how about starting with a sequence that has all entries equal on the right?

Comment: @JohnB so the forward orbit is not dense because the point you mentioned is not almost periodic for $\sigma$?

Comment: Better, it converges.